# Why won't this VBA program using ServerXMLHTTP60 authenticate properly?

Tags: vba, authentication

- I have 4 different queries of IPR 1.2.3.4 (ip-reputation) to IBM's Xforce database, using basic authentication (base64 encoded), as well as URL-reputation. My version in python works great, printing out the appropriate JSON information:

  ```
  ...
  if __name__ == '__main__':
     apiKey = "1234...."
     apiPwd = "5678..."
     result = requests.get('https://xforce-api.mybluemix.net:443/ipr/1.2.3.4', verify=False,auth=(apiKey, apiPwd))
     if result.status_code != 200:
         print( "~ Bad Status Code: {}".format(result.status_code))
     else:
         print("~ The result is {}".format(result.status_code))
         print("~ Rx Data={}".format(result._content))
  ```
- The version in Go (using demisto's goxforce from github) works great. After setting my environment-variable key and password, I issue the commandline:
  'xforceQuery -cmd ipr -q 1.2.3.4'

and it prints out the json information about 1.2.3.4, again, perfectly.

- I use the browser-utility called 'Postman', specify basic authentication with my user/key and password, headers of Accept: application/json, Accept-Language: en, and Content-Type: application/json, and, again, it gives me the proper information (see .gif, below)
  [image: Postman Xforce Get]
- On the other hand, I try the same thing in VBA, and I get '401 Error: Not authorized'.  What's wrong with this code?

  ```
  Public Sub testXF()

      Dim myKey As String
      Dim myPass As String

      myKey = "1234..."
      myPass = "5678..."

      pHtml = "xforce"
      Dim ohttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
      Set ohttp = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

      If timeout = 0 Then timeout = 60


      ohttp.Open "GET", "https://xforce-api.mybluemix.net:443/ipr/1.2.3.4", False, myKey, myPass

      With ohttp
         .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
         .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
         .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en"
         .SetTimeouts 0, 30 * 1000, 30 * 1000, timeout * 1000
         .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + _
             Base64Encode(myKey + ":" + myPass)
         .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
      End With

      ohttp.Send ("")
      With ohttp
          pStatus = .status
          pText = .ResponseText
          pResponseHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders()
      End With

      Debug.Print "GET", pStatus, pText
      Set ohttp = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Is there a proxy server?

Comment: Good question -- Even if there was, why would this not be a problem for python, Go, or Postman?  [I just don't know; nothing shows up in a google search, so far -- BTW, you can sign up for a key/password for free if you want to try and test this]

Comment: For your reference. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290761